# ngTable search filter just works on the current page, whereas I want global search

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ngtable

I'm using ngTable in Angularjs to implement pagination and search. The pagination works great, however search only works for the data visible on current page. How can I make a global search on the entire table irrespective of the page on which the data is displayed?
One thing I know is that the pagination is applied before the search filter, and that is causing this behaviour.
I'm kinda new to AngularJS, so if anyone can help me implementing a global search, it'd be great.

**JS:**

```
$scope.searchResp = function() {
    $scope.pagination = new NgTableParams({
        page : 1,
        count : 5
    }, {
        counts : [],
        dataset : $scope.moviejson    //moviejson has got moviecode and moviename fields.
    });
};
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="tabpane">
    Search by Movie Code: <input id="searchbar" ng-model="searchtxt.moviecode" type="text" placeholder="Enter Movie Code"><br /><br />
    Search by Movie Name: <input id="searchbar" ng-model="searchtxt.moviename" type="text" placeholder="Enter Error Name"><br /><br />
    <div>
        <table data-ng-table="pagination" class="table  table-bordered table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th  class="text-center" data-ng-bind="Movie Code"></th>
                    <th  class="text-center" data-ng-bind="Movie Name"></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr  data-ng-repeat="item in $data | filter : searchtxt">
                <td class="center-align" data-ng-bind="item.moviecode"></td>
                <td class="center-align" data-ng-bind="item.moviename"></td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

It would be great if somebody can help me in implementing global search, or guide to change the order of filters so that the search filter gets fired first and pagination is done later.

Comment: You could try to make move your table in a component witch receives the string as an input property. This way every time your string is modified the table should re-render so it should search in all the movies.

Comment: @Berci I don't think that's gonna work as still pagination would be carried out, can you be a bit more clear about your approach?

Comment: I would move the `div` which contains the table in a separate component. Send the moviecode and moviename strings as inputs. Then if needed you can even use filtered data (do the filtering in the component js and render only the filtered data in html).

Comment: nothing worked, so wrote a custom search function in the controller instead.